# QProcess to call matlab plotting

Tags: matlab, qt, plot

I try to get some sense of QProcess to matlab plotting by following program

```
 QProcess* p = new QProcess( NULL );
 p->startDetached(                    
 QString("/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/matlab"),   
 QStringList() << QString( "-r z=[1,2,3,4]; " ));
```

It worked well but when I try to use *plot(z)*

```
 QProcess* p = new QProcess( NULL );
 p->startDetached(                    
 QString("/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/matlab"),   
 QStringList() << QString( "-r z=[1,2,3,4]; plot(z); " ));
```

It showed error

> /Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/matlab: eval: line 1701: syntax error near unexpected token `z'
>
> /Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/matlab: eval: line 1701: `exec  "/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/maci64/../../Contents/MacOS/MATLAB_maci64"  -r z=[1,2,3,4]; plot(z) '

Can anyone give me a help to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `-r` and the script are separate arguments, and you should enclose the script in double quotes. Try `QStringList{"-r", "\"z=[1,2,3,4]; plot(z);\""}`. Use C++11, you're on a platform that has it :)

Comment: Thanks, but I get   `"z=[1,2,3,4];plot(z);"`
 |
    `{Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
}`